# Show message if package weight exceeds a given value

Tags: shipping, ce-1.9.0.1

I am using the table rate for shipping.  (weight vs destination)

If the weight is more than X I want a message or some indicator that will notify the client that shipping cost will be quoted and manually added to the invoice.

Possible?

Comment: Where do you want to display this message? In the cart? in the checkout?

Answer (score 1):

Create a block which displays the message after evaluating the cart/quote object. You can obtain the current cart using

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
```

In a function `exceedsWeightLimit()` of the block class you can iterate over the products and calculate the package weight. In the template you call this function and display your message.